# tracebackqq() with ifort leads to segmentation fault

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, intel-oneapi

Why does the following code lead to segmentation fault when compiled with `ifort`?

```
! testtrb.f90
program testtrb
    call tracebackqq()  ! This is for ifort
    !call backtrace()  ! This is for gfortran 
    print '(/1A/)', 'Finish.'
end program testtrb
```

Executing
`ifort testtrb.f90 ; ./a.out`,
I got

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000409FFA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.31.s  00007F6E2C9903C0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000000040746D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000000040383B  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004037E2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.31.so       00007F6E2C7B00B3  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004036EE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

The return of `ifort --version` is `ifort (IFORT) 19.1.1.217 20200306`. I also tried
`ifort (IFORT) 2021.1 Beta 20201112`, the result being similar. The value of `uname -r` is `5.9.0-050900-generic`, if it is helpful.

However, changing `tracebackqq` to `backtrace` and runing `gfortran testtrb.f90 ; ./a.out` , I get

```
#0  0x7f789588ad3a
#1  0x557b8f35119d
#2  0x557b8f351254
#3  0x7f789569f0b2
#4  0x557b8f3510cd
#5  0xffffffffffffffff

Finish.
```

This seems correct.

So why does `tracebackqq` give rise to SIGSEGV?

Any comments or criticism will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is not behaving as you expect for two reasons, both documented at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/t-to-z/tracebackqq.html

1. `Tracebackqq` has optional arguments. It thus requires an interface to
   be in scope at the calling point. This is achieved by using the
   `ifcore` module
2. Bizarrely by default `tracebackqq` terminates execution. To have the program continue execution you need to provide a non-default `user_exit_code`

So compiling and running the provided code on the login node of our local cluster I get the same behaviour as above:

```
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ cat tb.f90
! testtrb.f90
program testtrb
    call tracebackqq()  ! This is for ifort
    !call backtrace()  ! This is for gfortran 
    print '(/1A/)', 'Finish.'
end program testtrb
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 19.0.1.144 20181018
Copyright (C) 1985-2018 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort -g -traceback tb.f90
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ./a.out
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000409A03  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.12.s  000000381E40F710  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004800CF  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000406BE6  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004036A3  MAIN__                      3  tb.f90
a.out              0000000000403662  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.12.so       000000381E01ED5D  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000403569  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Adding use of the module stops the SIGSEGV but the code terminates before printing Finish as documented:

```
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ cat tb2.f90
! testtrb.f90
program testtrb
  Use ifcore, Only : tracebackqq
  Implicit None
  call tracebackqq()  ! This is for ifort
  !call backtrace()  ! This is for gfortran 
  print '(/1A/)', 'Finish.'
end program testtrb
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort -g -traceback tb2.f90
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ./a.out
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000406EFA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004036CE  MAIN__                      5  tb2.f90
a.out              0000000000403662  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.12.so       000000381E01ED5D  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000403569  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Finally adding the non-default `user_exit_code` gives the desired behaviour

```
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ cat tb3.f90
! testtrb.f90
program testtrb
  Use ifcore, Only : tracebackqq
  Implicit None
  call tracebackqq( user_exit_code = -1 )  ! This is for ifort
  !call backtrace()  ! This is for gfortran 
  print '(/1A/)', 'Finish.'
end program testtrb
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort -g -traceback tb3.f90
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ./a.out
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000406EFA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004036CE  MAIN__                      5  tb3.f90
a.out              0000000000403662  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.12.so       000000381E01ED5D  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000403569  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Finish.
```

Comment: Why did you compile without debug options? I think that especially line numbers would be very nice in this case.